# Return the size of a vector inside a list using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I want the following code to return the size of a vector that is inside a list.  When compiling with Rcpp, it returns the error `‘Rcpp::Vector<19>::Proxy’ {aka ‘class Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19>’} has no member named ‘size’`

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("
int f() {
  List X(2);
  X[0] = rep(0,2);
  X[1] = rep(0,3);
  return X[0].size();
}")

f()
```

**UPDATE**

I found one solution: to cast X[0] before returning.  Here's the code:

```
cppFunction("
int f() {
  List X(2);
  X[0] = rep(0,2);
  X[1] = rep(0,3);
  return ((IntegerVector)X[0]).size();
}")
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would recommend migrating from package `inline` to Rcpp Attributes. Most of us did around 2013 or 2014; see the updated intro vignette.

Second, you function is correct as it stands; the following (slightly) modified version returns two vectors in a list:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List f() {
  List X(2);
  X[0] = rep(0,2);
  X[1] = rep(0,3);
  return X;
}

/*** R
f()
*/
```

*However*, writing template expressions is hard. There is nothing wrong with your *idea* but sometimes the compiler needs help.  So for example assigning the vectors first to `NumericVectors` object, then querying their size would work---and you could then assign them to the list:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List g() {
  IntegerVector v0 = rep(0,2);
  IntegerVector v1 = rep(0,3);
  Rcout << "Sizes are " << v0.size() << " and " << v1.size() << std::endl;
  return List::create(v0, v1);
}
```

Running both (after also adding a call to `g()` at the end) I get:

```
R> sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/61994530/answer.cpp")

R> f()
[[1]]
[1] 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0


R> g()
Sizes are 2 and 3
[[1]]
[1] 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0

R>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my code programmatically decides how many X[i]'s to generate, so I cannot do a List:create(v0, ..., vN).  Any other idea?

Comment: As suggested, I updated the question (and my code) to use Rcpp Attributes.  Thank you!

Comment: Just do as you did before and create `List x(n);` for given `n`.

Comment: Or as we do in `f()`.  And for what it is worth you _still_ don't show use of `n` either.

Comment: Thank you, but none of these ideas allowed me to achieve what I wanted (i.e., to return X[0].size()), as the compiler still couldn't infer that X[0] was a vector (I cannot call List::create(X[0], X[1], ...), as the number of X's varies).  The thing that ended up working was to do an explicit casting of X[0] when returning.  I updated the question with this solution.  I'm not sure if this incurs into a performance penalty, but will check.

Comment: a) That is entirely equivalent code. b) Your edited function does not make too much sense as it stands as you instantiate two vectors only to have them go out of score.